# Finding Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line

Tags: java, csv, import, deeplearning4j

Is there anyway we could find line number of "Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line"? I'm trying to read CSV file in java, but getting error most probably because - there is a quote is opened but isn't closed. 
I'm using CSVRecordReader of deeplearning4j - datavec.

The idea is that if I find that line number, I can remove/correct it. But problem is, I can not find the line number when error is thrown.

If you have any suggestion - in Java or other, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to find lines which have odd number quotes, just count the quotes.

Comment: I thought so, but what if we've a quote that's escaped?

Comment: If you know the escape character, you can omit the quote after the escape character.

Comment: Or you can use another csv library. I believe there are libraries which can detect the error.

Comment: Thanks! I could use other library, but that library provides so many other functionalities, and is tightly integrated. I need to live with that library. I therefore have to correct/remove file....

Answer (score 2):

For datavec, I would consider using a debugger.
You could easily put a breakpoint on: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/datavec/datavec-api/src/main/java/org/datavec/api/records/reader/impl/csv/CSVRecordReader.java#L181 and see where it fails to parse the file.

You could also just write your own recordreader instead. The person suggesting the alternative csv library didn't have the full context, so let me redirect this to a proper solution to the library: You say it's tightly integrated, but you're actually misunderstanding *where* it's coupled.

You can use any recordreader you want. You don't have to use the ones we provide. The components are coupled at an interface level only.

On your particular csv problem,  you could also just clean up the csv file. My solution was focused on trying to debug it within your ide.

Either way, you have multiple options for a solution here. If you have a particular suggestion on usability, you are more than welcome to file an issue as well: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues

Answer (score 1):

Below is a method to determine if the  number of specific character is odd.

```
static boolean oddChar(char escape, char target, String line) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        while (i < line.length() && line.charAt(i) == escape)
            i += 2;
        if (i < line.length() && line.charAt(i) == target)
            cnt++;
    }
    return (cnt & 1) == 1;
}
```

For example

```
oddChar('/', '\'', "shsb'jddn'sjs/'nddn////'bdbd///'");
```

There are 3 `'`.

Answer (score 1):

[univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial.html) handles unescaped quotes and you can configure it to raise an exception if any is found. The exception will print out the character position in the file, the row and everything you need to locate the source of the problem.

Just use:

`settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.RAISE_ERROR);`

You can also use the method [currentParsedContent](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/common/ParsingContext.java#L110) from the `ParsingContext` object available from within a `RowProcessor`. This returns the entire `String` that was used to generate a single record. If you write these to an output file, you will end up re-generating the input CSV.

You can leverage this to locate where the problematic unescaped quote is and fix the file so you can input it back to the library you are currently using.

Hope it helps.

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)