# CSVRecordReader and Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line

Tags: java, csv, deeplearning4j, dl4j, univocity

I have a problem with the datasets that I am using. They are CSV that contain fake news. My problem is with the `CSVRecordReader` class, which is what DataVec (Deeplearning4j) offers me. I am trying to make a spark transformation process. My problem is the well-known "*Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line*" error.

Searching on the Internet everyone recommends that you look for the line where this occurs and fix the problem in the csv, but this is going to be very difficult because the dataset contains parts of the articles (which can be true or false). These articles contain many quotes in quotes, among other things typical of articles.

Looking for a solution I ended up implementing my own CSVRecordReader using the Univocity csv parser library which is very flexible and solves all the problems that the current `CSVRecordReader` has, but now I find another dilemma and it is that **the parser of this library does not implement the interface** `Serializable` **and running the transformation in Apache Spark throws the exception**

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser

How can I solve my problem?

[image]

My own CSVRecordReader code

```
package cu.desoft.cav.RecordReader;

import com.univocity.parsers.common.IterableResult;
import com.univocity.parsers.common.ParsingContext;
import com.univocity.parsers.common.ResultIterator;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;
import org.datavec.api.records.Record;
import org.datavec.api.records.metadata.RecordMetaData;
import org.datavec.api.records.metadata.RecordMetaDataLine;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.LineRecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit;
import org.datavec.api.split.InputSplit;
import org.datavec.api.writable.Text;
import org.datavec.api.writable.Writable;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author: Acosta email: yunielacost738@gmail.com
 * created at: 11/25/2019
 */

public class UltraCSVRecordReader extends LineRecordReader {
    public static final char DEFAULT_DELIMITER = ',';
    public static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE = '"';
    public static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE_ESCAPE = '"';
    public static final char DEFAULT_CHAR_TO_ESCAPE_QUOTE_ESCAPING = '\0';
    private CsvParser csvParser;
    private CsvParserSettings settings;
    private ResultIterator<String[], ParsingContext> iterator;
    public UltraCSVRecordReader() {
        this(0, DEFAULT_DELIMITER, DEFAULT_QUOTE, DEFAULT_QUOTE_ESCAPE, DEFAULT_CHAR_TO_ESCAPE_QUOTE_ESCAPING);
    }

/**
 * @param unknownFormat if you can't know line endings, column delimiters and quotation characters set unknownFormat=true
 *                      for automatic detection
 */
public UltraCSVRecordReader(boolean unknownFormat) {
    this();
    if (unknownFormat) {
        settings = new CsvParserSettings();
        settings.detectFormatAutomatically();
        csvParser = new CsvParser(settings);
    }
}

public UltraCSVRecordReader(CsvParserSettings settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
    csvParser = new CsvParser(settings);
}

/**
 * @param skipNumLines              number of lines to skip
 * @param delimiter                 (default ,): value used to separate individual fields in the input
 * @param quote                     (default "): value used for escaping values where the fields delimiter is part of
 *                                  the value (e.g. the value "a,b" is parse as a , b).
 * @param quoteEscape               (default "): value used for escaping the quote character inside an already escaped value
 *                                  (e.g. the value " "" a,b "" " is parse as " a , b ").
 * @param charToEscapeQuoteEscaping (default \0): value used for escaping the quote escape character, when quote and quote escape are different
 *                                  (e.g. the value “\ " a , b " \” is parsed as \ " a , b " \, if quote = ", quoteEscape = \ and charToEscapeQuoteEscaping = \).
 */
public UltraCSVRecordReader(long skipNumLines, char delimiter, char quote, char quoteEscape,
                            char charToEscapeQuoteEscaping) {
    settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setDelimiter(delimiter);
    settings.getFormat().setQuote(quote);
    settings.getFormat().setQuoteEscape(quoteEscape);
    settings.getFormat().setCharToEscapeQuoteEscaping(charToEscapeQuoteEscaping);
    settings.setNumberOfRowsToSkip(skipNumLines);
    csvParser = new CsvParser(settings);
}

/**
 * @param skipNumLines number of lines to skip
 */
public UltraCSVRecordReader(long skipNumLines) {
    this(skipNumLines, DEFAULT_DELIMITER, DEFAULT_QUOTE, DEFAULT_QUOTE_ESCAPE, DEFAULT_CHAR_TO_ESCAPE_QUOTE_ESCAPING);
}

/**
 * @param skipNumLines number of lines to skip
 * @param delimiter    (default ,): value used to separate individual fields in the input
 */
public UltraCSVRecordReader(long skipNumLines, char delimiter) {
    this(skipNumLines, delimiter, DEFAULT_QUOTE, DEFAULT_QUOTE_ESCAPE, DEFAULT_CHAR_TO_ESCAPE_QUOTE_ESCAPING);
}

/**
 * @param skipNumLines number of lines to skip
 * @param delimiter    (default ,): value used to separate individual fields in the input
 * @param quote        (default "): value used for escaping values where the fields delimiter is part of
 *                     the value (e.g. the value "a,b" is parse as a , b).
 */
public UltraCSVRecordReader(long skipNumLines, char delimiter, char quote) {
    this(skipNumLines, delimiter, quote, DEFAULT_QUOTE_ESCAPE, DEFAULT_CHAR_TO_ESCAPE_QUOTE_ESCAPING);
}

/**
 * @param skipNumLines number of lines to skip
 * @param delimiter    (default ,): value used to separate individual fields in the input
 * @param quote        (default "): value used for escaping values where the fields delimiter is part of
 *                     the value (e.g. the value "a,b" is parse as a , b).
 * @param quoteEscape  (default "): value used for escaping the quote character inside an already escaped value
 *                     (e.g. the value " "" a,b "" " is parse as " a , b ").
 */
public UltraCSVRecordReader(long skipNumLines, char delimiter, char quote, char quoteEscape) {
    this(skipNumLines, delimiter, quote, quoteEscape, DEFAULT_CHAR_TO_ESCAPE_QUOTE_ESCAPING);
}

@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    super.initialize(split);
    this.initialize(((FileSplit) split).getRootDir());
}

public UltraCSVRecordReader maxLengthCharactersToParser(int numberCharacters) {
    this.settings.setMaxCharsPerColumn(numberCharacters);
    this.csvParser = new CsvParser(this.settings);
    return this;
}

public void initialize(File file) {
    IterableResult<String[], ParsingContext> iterate = this.csvParser.iterate(file);
    iterator = iterate.iterator();
}

protected List<Writable> parseLine(String line) {
    String[] split;
    split = this.csvParser.parseLine(line);
    List<Writable> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String value : split) {
        values.add(new Text(value));
    }
    return values;
}

public List<List<Writable>> next(int num) {
    List<List<Writable>> ret = new ArrayList<>(Math.min(num, 10000));
    int count = 0;

    while (this.hasNext() && count++ < num) {
        ret.add(this.next());
    }
    return ret;
}

public List<Writable> next() {
    String[] valuesSplit = iterator.next();
    List<Writable> values = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (String value : valuesSplit) {
            values.add(new Text(value));
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(values);
        System.out.println("================================");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(valuesSplit));
    }

    return values;
}

public boolean batchesSupported() {
    return true;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return iterator.hasNext();
}

public Record nextRecord() {
    List<Writable> next = this.next();
    URI uri = this.locations != null && this.locations.length >= 1 ? this.locations[this.splitIndex] : null;
    RecordMetaData meta = new RecordMetaDataLine(this.lineIndex - 1, uri, UltraCSVRecordReader.class);
    return new org.datavec.api.records.impl.Record(next, meta);
}

public Record loadFromMetaData(RecordMetaData recordMetaData) throws IOException {
    return this.loadFromMetaData(Collections.singletonList(recordMetaData)).get(0);
}

public List<Record> loadFromMetaData(List<RecordMetaData> recordMetaDatas) throws IOException {
    List<Record> list = super.loadFromMetaData(recordMetaDatas);

    for (Record r : list) {
        String line = r.getRecord().get(0).toString();
        r.setRecord(this.parseLine(line));
    }

    return list;
}

public void reset() {
    super.reset();
}

public CsvParser getCsvParser() {
    return csvParser;
}
}
```

Example DATASET

> "uuid","ord_in_thread","author","published","title","text","language","crawled","site_url","country","domain_rank","thread_title","spam_score","main_img_url","replies_count","participants_count","likes","comments","shares","type"
>   "6a175f46bcd24d39b3e962ad0f29936721db70db",0,"Barracuda Brigade","2016-10-26T21:41:00.000+03:00","Muslims BUSTED: They Stole Millions In Gov’t Benefits","Print They should pay all the back all the money plus interest. The entire family and everyone who came in with them need to be deported asap. Why did it take two years to bust them? 
>   Here we go again …another group stealing from the government and taxpayers! A group of Somalis stole over four million in government benefits over just 10 months! 
>   We’ve reported on numerous cases like this one where the Muslim refugees/immigrants commit fraud by scamming our system…It’s way out of control! More Related","english","2016-10-27T01:49:27.168+03:00","100percentfedup.com","US",25689,"Muslims BUSTED: They Stole Millions In Gov’t Benefits",0,"http://bb4sp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Fullscreen-capture-10262016-83501-AM.bmp.jpg",0,1,0,0,0,"bias"

This is my transform process

```
package cu.desoft.cav.preprocessing;

import cu.desoft.cav.RecordReader.UltraCSVRecordReader;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.RecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVRecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.transform.TransformProcess;
import org.datavec.api.transform.schema.Schema;
import org.datavec.api.writable.Writable;
import org.datavec.spark.transform.SparkTransformExecutor;
import org.datavec.spark.transform.misc.StringToWritablesFunction;
import org.datavec.spark.transform.misc.WritablesToStringFunction;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * author: acosta
 * email: yunielacosta738@gmail.com
 * Created on: 2/3/20
 */
public class FakeNewsTransformation {
    private final String DATSETS_PATH = "data/FakeNews/";

    public void transform(boolean useSparkLocal) {
        Schema schema = new Schema.Builder()
                .addColumnString("uuid")
                .addColumnInteger("ord_in_thread")
                .addColumnString("author")
                .addColumnString("published")
                .addColumnsString("title","text","language","crawled","site_url","country")
                .addColumnInteger("domain_rank")
                .addColumnString("thread_title")
                .addColumnsInteger("spam_score","main_img_url","replies_count","participants_count","likes","comments","shares")
                .addColumnCategorical("type", Arrays.asList("bias", "bs","conspiracy","fake","hate","junksci","satire","state"))
                .build();

        TransformProcess tp = new TransformProcess.Builder(schema)
                .removeColumns("uuid", "ord_in_thread","author","published","site_url","country","thread_title")
                .categoricalToInteger("type")
                .build();

        int numActions = tp.getActionList().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < numActions; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n\n===============================");
            System.out.println("--- Schema after step " + i +
                    " (" + tp.getActionList().get(i) + ")--");
            System.out.println(tp.getSchemaAfterStep(i));
        }

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.nd4j.Nd4jRegistrator");
        if (useSparkLocal) {
            sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]");
        }

        sparkConf.setAppName("Fake News Spanish Corpus dataset transformation");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        //Load our data using Spark
        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(DATSETS_PATH + "fake.csv");
        int skipNumLines = 1;
        //We first need to parse this format. It's comma-delimited (CSV) format, so let's parse it using CSVRecordReader:
        RecordReader rr = new UltraCSVRecordReader();
//        RecordReader rr = new CSVRecordReader();
        JavaRDD<List<Writable>> parsedInputData = lines.map(new StringToWritablesFunction(rr));

        //Now, let's execute the transforms we defined earlier:
        JavaRDD<List<Writable>> processedData = SparkTransformExecutor.execute(parsedInputData, tp);

        //For the sake of this example, let's collect the data locally and print it:
        JavaRDD<String> processedAsString = processedData.map(new WritablesToStringFunction(","));
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<PATH>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        File dataset = new File("dataset/FakeNews");
        if (dataset.exists()) {
            try {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dataset);
                System.out.println("DELETE THE DIRECTORY");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("The directory was not delete");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dataset.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<END-PATH>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        processedAsString.saveAsTextFile("file://" + dataset.getAbsolutePath());   //To save locally
        //processedAsString.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://your/hdfs/save/path/here");   //To save to hdfs

        List<String> processedCollected = processedAsString.collect();
        List<String> inputDataCollected = lines.collect();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FakeNewsTransformation().transform(true);
    }
}
```

This is the output error when i use CSVRecordReader (DataVec)

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line
    at org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVRecordReader.parseLine(CSVRecordReader.java:183)
    at org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVRecordReader.next(CSVRecordReader.java:175)
    at org.datavec.spark.transform.misc.StringToWritablesFunction.call(StringToWritablesFunction.java:41)
    at org.datavec.spark.transform.misc.StringToWritablesFunction.call(StringToWritablesFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1040)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1210)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1210)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line
    at org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.SerializableCSVParser.parseLine(SerializableCSVParser.java:276)
    at org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.SerializableCSVParser.parseLine(SerializableCSVParser.java:186)
    at org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVRecordReader.parseLine(CSVRecordReader.java:181)
    ... 21 more
```

And this is the Serialization Problem when i use my own CSVRecordReader with univocity csv parser(this library do not implement Serializable)

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at cu.desoft.cav.preprocessing.FakeNewsTransformation.transform(FakeNewsTransformation.java:71)
    at cu.desoft.cav.preprocessing.FakeNewsTransformation.main(FakeNewsTransformation.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser, value: com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser@75b6dd5b)
    - field (class: cu.desoft.cav.RecordReader.UltraCSVRecordReader, name: csvParser, type: class com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser)
    - object (class cu.desoft.cav.RecordReader.UltraCSVRecordReader, cu.desoft.cav.RecordReader.UltraCSVRecordReader@1fedf0a4)
    - field (class: org.datavec.spark.transform.misc.StringToWritablesFunction, name: recordReader, type: interface org.datavec.api.records.reader.RecordReader)
    - object (class org.datavec.spark.transform.misc.StringToWritablesFunction, org.datavec.spark.transform.misc.StringToWritablesFunction@465b38e6)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, name: fun$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you to add the full stacktrace of the error, which would be more useful to understand where the problem could be.

Comment: Ok thanks I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You either have to fix the line in the CSV causing your error. Or implement your record reader to be serializable.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456905/finding-un-terminated-quoted-field-at-end-of-csv-line) univocity-parsers "handles unescaped quotes and you can configure it to raise an exception if any is found." Maybe try that?

Comment: I already implemented my own RecordReader using univocity csv parser, but no class in the library implements the serialisable interface so when I use it with spark it throws the second error. My CSVRecordReader works perfectly alone but not together with spark

Comment: Right. So you have to either modify it to work with spark or fix the line in the csv file. The link above tells you how to print out exceptions for unescaped quotes. This way you can fix the file.